# Retrieving text contents from javascript dialog boxes using Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there any way for a Chrome extension to retrieve the text content from the popup dialog boxes created by the javascript confirm() or alert() functions?

Comment: Only by overwriting the functions.

Comment: Yep. For the overwrite code use [Insert code into the page context using a content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704)